# Optical Simulation Tool

Tags: optics, visible-light, simulations, software

I am a student and trying to design an aperture from which a light will pass will project on a sensor. I tried to find some software simulation tool for this purpose where i can draw the aperture (entrance side) and put diffuser or lens and then see the response of the light for some specific wavelength. I found one tool "Synopsys Code V" but it is very paid solution. So can anyone tell me some substitute for this. I am looking for Free simulation tools.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Software for geometrical optics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6682/)

Comment: There's two possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6682/, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38865/

Comment: @tpg2114...The link u mentioned have links for software tools which only helps in making drawing but not simulation tools...i want to see real-time response also.

Comment: I have experience with OSLO, it is not very user-friendly but it works and they have a free version for students. Refraction index is wavelength-dependent, if this is what you need.