# Simulation software for wave optics

Tags: optics, waves, resource-recommendations, simulations, software

I am using [COMSOL multiphysics](http://www.comsol.com/comsol-multiphysics) Optics module for wave optics simulations and I am wondering if there is better simulation software for wave optics simulations (no multiphysics needed).

Like software which is dedicated for wave optics only and performs faster.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6682/, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38865/ and links therein.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. In the first link, it is about ray optics. In the second list, it is about free simulators. I want to find out the best software for WAVE optics simulations (free of charge or with price). Thanks